# Not able to run sample karate bdd test

Tags: karate

Trying to run a sample BDD test

Background:
* configure ssl = true

Scenario: get all users

Given url 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
When method get
Then status 200

While the statement 'When method get' executes, i get error 
Error: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443 [jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/104.31.87.157, jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/104.31.86.157] failed: Connection timed out: connect

I am able to ping this address from my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your browser is using a proxy server. No body else has reported this problem, so you need to check your environment.

Comment: Are there any configuration to be done from framework point of view which i might have missed? Any help on debug this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the best thing is you try the quickstart: https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart - also why don't you try to connect to the actual server you want to test

Comment: Got this run by adding proxy. Thanks for your help.